# Blender freezes when trying to bake normal map

Tags: modeling, normals, baking

I am trying to bake a normal map for a model I made but keep encountering the problem that blender freezes up for hours when I try to bake the normal map from a high poly to a low poly version of the mesh (with the help of a cage) And at first I thought it is my bad laptop (4 gb ram, i7-4700MQ CPU 2.40 GHz, NVIDIA geforce GT 740M ) but on a better computer it still froze up, on which I never had issues with baking before.

Could someone take a look at the file and see if something is wrong with it? Because I can't find a cause..

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C9AxyCNdtdMmz0L87N3qx6Y7RwCltuYH

Comment: how many polygons does your scene have? ~100Mb is to much for me to download :)

Comment: @monatsen it's 4,908,206 polygons!

Comment: *" it's 4,908,206 polygons"* that's going to be the reason.. It's a lot of geometry to project and compute.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, 
I downloaded your file, baked a 2k normalmap and it took me less than 5 min (Macbook Pro).

So, I could not reproduce the behavior you mentioned and **the only thing I changed was to reduce the preview subdivision** of your multiresolution modifier on the highpoly mesh.

[image: baking result]

Comment: Oh my that's amazing! What settings did you bake it on? Could you send me the map?

Comment: the map is a standard openGL tangent normal map. there are some small baking errors but I recommend to  reduce the preview subdivision to 1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/o553i50tnj9ryio/elfstro_nor.tif?dl=0